# Proof of "a sequence of uniformly convergent bounded functions converges to a bounded function"

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

Let $A \ne \emptyset$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let $f_n:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions and let $f_n \to f$ uniformly in $A$. My book proves the theorem "a sequence of uniformly convergent bounded functions converges to a bounded function" using the uniformly convergence definition given by the Cauchy convergence, meaning $f_n \to f$ uniformly in $A \iff \forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists N_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{s.t}. \forall x \in A \ \text{if} \ n,m>N_{\varepsilon}\ \text{then} \ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \varepsilon $.

I've tried to prove it in another way, but I'm not sure if this is correct. Here is my attempt: by hypothesis $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly in $A$, meaning that for all $\varepsilon>0$ exists $N_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x \in A$, $n>N_{\varepsilon} \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. This mean that $-\varepsilon+f_n(x) < f(x) < f_n(x)+\varepsilon$. By hypothesis $f_n$ is bounded in $A$, meaning that there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $-M \leq f_n(x) \leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So it is $-\varepsilon-M \leq -\varepsilon+f_n(x) < f(x) < f_n(x)+\varepsilon<M+\varepsilon$ and this implies that $-\varepsilon-M < f(x) < \varepsilon+M$, and since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary it follows that $-M \leq f(x) \leq M$, so $f$ is bounded.

I suspect that this is wrong because I don't see where I used the uniform convergence, indeed I believe that when I estimate using $-M \leq f_n(x) \leq M$ it isn't correct because the boundedness of $f_n$ is referred to "for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$" and I don't have information if it is valid "for all $x\in A$" too, so to do that I should have something like a "uniform boundedness", meaning I should have that there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x \in A$ it is $-M \leq f_n(x) \leq M$. It seems like that in my proof the constant $M$ depends on $x$ and this is not ok, but I'm not sure if it is the problem. If it is wrong, can someone explain me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in what you did is when you say *"by hypothesis $f_n$ is bounded in $A$, meaning that there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $-M \leq f_n(x) \leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$."*

The problem is that $M$ depends on $n$ (not on $x$). To get rid of the issue, you can proceed as follows.

As $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$, it exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert \le 1$ for all $x \in A$. Therefore

$$\vert f(x) \vert \le 1 + \vert f_N(x) \vert$$ for $x \in A$. As $f_N$ is supposed to be bounded (we speak of only one map here), it exists $M \gt 0$ such that $\vert f_N(x) \vert \lt M$ for all $x \in A$ and

$$\vert f(x) \vert \le 1 + \vert f_N(x) \vert \le 1 + M$$ for all $x \in A$. Proving as desired that $f$ is bounded on $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two things: for $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq 1 \implies |f(x)| \leq 1+|f_N(x)|$ you're using the fact that $||f_n(x)|-|f(x)|| \leq |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq 1 \implies |f(x)| \leq 1+|f_n(x)|$ and the fact that the inequality is valid for $n \geq N$ so it is valid in particular for $n=N$?
The second thing is that I still don't get why $M$ depending on $n$ makes the proof not correct, can you explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: @ZaWarudo Answer to you first question is yes. Regarding the second one, the issue is that as $M$ depends on $n$, you should not even write $M$ but $M_n$. But then, how can you bound $M_n$ apart from taking a specific one?

Comment: Ok, so maybe now I get it. Since $M_n$ is a constant but depending on $n$ it is actually a sequence, so with my first reasoning I actually proved $-\varepsilon+M_n < f(x) < \varepsilon +M_n$ which means that $f$ is between two sequences and of course this not mean that it is bounded (for example it can be $-\varepsilon +n < f(x) < \varepsilon +n$); but since I have no control over $M_n$ I can't conclude. Instead, I have control on $f_n$ when $n \geq N$ and so the most natural thing to do is to fix $n=N$. This is the correct point of view?

Comment: @ZaWarudo You got! Exactly that.

Comment: Thanks again, you're gentle. One last thing: you've said in the first comment "how can you bound $M_n$ apart from taking a specific one?". I have interpreted it in the sense that it is not possible to take one specific. If I've interpreted correctly, why is it not possible? I suppose that it isn't because we have the existential quantifier for $M_n$, meaning we know that exists a sequence $M_n$ such that $-M_n < f_n(x) < M_n$, but we can't fix it because we just know it exists but we don't know what it is; it would be different if I had "for all $M_n$ it is $-M_n < f_n(x) < M_n$". This is why?

Comment: In fact, the issue if you don't fix $n$ is that $M_n$ may not be bounded as $n$ vary. If you fix one, the issue disappears.

Comment: Oh okay! But then couldn't we just fix $n=N$ in my attempt of proof using $M_N$ as bound?

Comment: Yes. This is what I did. However you have to relate this $N$ to a proper $\epsilon$. This is why in my answer I chose $\epsilon = 1$.